# Insert multiple rows based on certain conditions

Tags: excel, vba, insert

Can you please help with a VBA solution on how to increment rows(output) based on certain existing rows(input)

I'd like to insert multiple rows based on "No of rows" column and for each row to concatenate certain value cell with incremental value.
Also for dates, I'd like to increment with 1 day for each new row.
Is there a way to do it in VBA based on that specific pattern? thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Transform Data: Insert Rows

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**Almost**

```vb
Sub TransformData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to the source array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Return the processed values from the source array
    ' in the destination array.
    
    ' Calculate rows.
    Dim arCount As Long
    arCount = Application.Sum(srg.Columns(cCount).Resize(srCount - 1).Offset(1))
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = srCount + arCount
    
    ' Define array.
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 1
    
    Dim sr As Long, ar As Long, c As Long
    
    ' Write headers.
    For c = 1 To cCount
        dData(1, c) = sData(1, c)
    Next c
    
    ' Write data.
    For sr = 2 To srCount
        ar = sData(sr, cCount)
        dr = dr + 1
        For c = 1 To cCount
            dData(dr, c) = sData(sr, c)
        Next c
        If ar > 0 Then
            For ar = 1 To ar
                dr = dr + 1
                dData(dr, 1) = sData(sr, 1) & " V" & ar
                dData(dr, 3) = dData(dr - 1, 3)
                dData(dr, 4) = dData(dr - 1, 4) + 1
                dData(dr, 5) = dData(dr - 1, 5) + 1
                dData(dr, 8) = "V" & ar
                dData(dr, 9) = dData(dr - 1, 9)
            Next ar
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").Resize(drCount, cCount)
    
    dws.UsedRange.Clear
    drg.Value = dData
    
    drg.Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    drg.Columns.AutoFit
    
    MsgBox "Data transformed.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much! I'm trying to update in the same "Sheet1", not separate sheets and just add the rest of rows. do I still need  Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1" ?

Comment: Then you can use just one constant. Name it more appropriately like `WS_NAME` and use a single worksheet variable e.g. `ws`. You can also use `Set drg = srg.Resize(...)`. On the other hand, maybe keep it as-is and use twice the same worksheet name so it stays ready for two worksheets if you change your mind.

Comment: can I add and use additional columns after column J (c10) and have this macro work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little unclear on what your criteria are, but hopefully this can get you started (revised):

```
Dim RowCounter As Long
Dim NumRows As Long
Dim NewRowCount As Long

'Capturing the total number of rows, minus the header row.
NumRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) - 1

RowCounter = 2      'Starting with row 2
For i = 1 To NumRows
    
    'Determine the number of new rows to be added.
    NewRowCount = Cells(RowCounter, 10).Value
    
    'Insert the appropriate number of rows based on the value in col 10.
    Range("A" & RowCounter + 1).EntireRow.Resize(NewRowCount).Insert shift:=xlDown
    
    'Replicate the values into the new rows from the current row.
    'Make your customizations here for which cells get incremented, left blank, etc.
    For j = 1 To NewRowCount
        Range("A" & RowCounter).EntireRow.Copy Range("A" & RowCounter + j)
    
    Next j

    'Moving to the next original row to be processed.
    RowCounter = RowCounter + NewRowCount + 1

Next i
```

You'll want to then modify the code to increment your dates as desired, as well as make the adjustments to col. A values where you are concatenating for the result of "AAA_V1", for example.

Comment: After re-reading, I'm seeing where some of your criteria are. Reworking....